# react native отловить пуш уведомления OneSignal

Tags: react-native, уведомления, push-уведомления, push

есть приложение написанное на react-native, в качестве пуш уведомлений используется OneSignal, моя задача заключается в том, чтобы отловить пуши и сохранить их в локальное хранилище когда приложение закрыто, в данный момент мне удается отловить только когда приложение либо открыто, либо работает в фоне, скажите реально ли это сделать? в документации по OneSignal ничего подходящего не нашел, спасибо.

Comment: на англоязычной версии предложили использовать notifee, попробую, о результатах напишу.

Comment: Я пробовал react-native-background-actions, но когда приложение выгружалось из памяти, то такс останавливался. Есть еще варианты:
react-native-background-job
react-native-queue я в процессе проверки последних двух.